# Update ListView of previous activity in background

Tags: android, android-listview

I have question regarding my previous ListView activity.

I have my ListView which is continue updating using socket connection, now when I click on any of the list row i can go to my next screen now when i come back to my previous ListView screen my ListView is start updating again but i want to keep updating my ListView in a background when i am on my nextscreen.

Something like i want to keep my previous screen alive when i am on my nextscreen.

Comment: Why are you trying to update a View the user can't see?

Comment: I want to keep my statistic up to date in background because my socket  continuously listening json messages from server

Comment: Then use a `Service` for the background jobs. You shouldn't be doing anything in the background using an `Activity`. In fact, I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like your the code you are using to load the data for your `ListView` is tied to your `Activity`.
For instance you have an `AsyncTask` or `Thread` in your `Activity` that cointains your `ListView` and you use it to download data, or do whatever is needed to get the data to populate the list. I also assume you start it in one of the `Activity` lifecycle methods e.g. `onCreate()`.

If that is the case then you should consider seperating the code used for getting the data for the list from your activity code.

One way to do this is to use a `Service` which will be able to run independantly of the rest of your application and do all the heavy lifting involed with fetching the data for your list. You can communicate with the service from anywhere in your application. The `Service` can save the data to a database. Then all you have to do in your Activity is query the database and populate the adapter to get the latest data without much delay.

You can read more about services here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

You could (and probably should) do what Paul suggested **or** you could change to way you switch your screens by using `Fragments` or a `ViewFlipper`. This way you still run your `AsyncTask` or `Thread` while doing something else on a different page.